# How do I handle large messages in AWS SQS using the SQS Extended Client Library for Java?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-java

I know that SQS can handle messages larger than 256kb, using the Java [extended client library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-s3-messages.html), but what's confusing me is where does this go? Do I upload it as a separate app?

Answer (score 2):

You include it in the **producer** & the **consumer** - the library then automatically handles:

- Stores your large message in S3
- Sends a message onto the queue, that contains the URL
- Retrieves the (message) object from the S3 bucket based on the URL
- Deletes the (message) object from an S3 bucket

It is an extra dependency, that you can manage using [a variety of dependency management tools](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.amazonaws/amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib/2.0.2/jar).

For example, if you're using Maven:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Or if you're using Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib:2.0.2'
```